# How to transfer int array of drawable from a class to another class

Tags: java, android, arrays, int

I just started to learn java. I am trying to transfer an int array of drawable images from a class to another. this is what I tried:

The first class as follows

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, target.class);
intent.putExtra("symbols", symbols);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

The target class as follows

```
int symbols = getIntent().getIntExtra("symbols", 0);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.himg);
    iv.setImageResource(symbols);
```

when I ran it, the image didn't show up in the target class. Any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an array with android-intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215000/passing-an-array-with-android-intent)

Answer (score 1):

Try this You can send & read Integer array using intent.

**Source Activity**

```
int myDrawableArray[] = {R.drawable.icon_home,R.drawable.icon_search,R.drawable.icon_plus};
Intent switchIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
switchIntent.putExtra("myDrawableArray", myDrawableArray);
startActivity(switchIntent);
```

**Destination Activity**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int[] myDrawableArray = extras.getIntArray("myDrawableArray");
```

**Use image from array :**

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.himg);
iv.setImageResource(myDrawableArray[2]);
```

I have use static index of array you can pass index via intent as per requirement.